# Start Segue After Completion Of Social Sharing

Tags: ios, swift, segue, facebook-social-plugins

I want to let users share some posts from my app with the help of the social framework. But after the post button in the social framework, the segue is not starting. How can I handle this?

```
var shareToFacebook : SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
shareToFacebook.addImage(self.Img.image)
self.presentViewController(shareToFacebook, animated: true, completion: nil)
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToStarting", sender: self)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to present the view controller in this method

```
var completionHandler: SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler!
```

You can use the above method like this

```
var shareToFacebook : SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
shareToFacebook.addImage(self.Img.image)
shareToFacebook.completionHandler = {
    (result:SLComposeViewControllerResult) in

    }
self.presentViewController(shareToFacebook, animated: true, completion: nil)
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToStarting", sender: self)
```

Comment: Hello Rajatp, I updated as above, but now netiher the post on facebook view is coming nor the segue is starting. May I miss anything else?

Comment: the above code has nothing to do with presenting SLComposeViewController as this code will execute when you press post or cancel on the dialog.

Comment: Hello Rajatp no I am getting the error as below and the segue is not starting: 2015-08-31 22:11:33.083 MyProject[4005:554148] Warning: Attempt to present <MyProject.tabBarController: 0x1664ef80>  on <MyProject.PostVC: 0x1723a200> which is already presenting (null)

Comment: Edited my answer.Check

Comment: Now inside the completionhandler perform your segue

Comment: Still same error, I guess it tries to perform the segue before the post is invalidated, for this reason it may not start? <MyProject.tabBarController: 0x170be0e0>  on <MyProject.postVC: 0x16bc7200> which is already presenting (null)
2015-08-31 22:30:27.395 MyProject[4096:561013] plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post invalidated

Comment: i think one of your view is presenting and you are presenting your SLComposeViewController in it thats why you are getting this issue

Comment: Solved by entering a function into the completion handler and putting the segue into the function. Somehow it started to work. Is is possible that the completion handler starts the function if only post is clicked and nothing when cancel is clicked? Thank you very much by the way Rajatp.

Comment: Yes inside the block you have a variable result, which will let you know when user pressed post or canceled the post.